# How far away is the horizon as seen from top of a mountain 1 mile high?

Tags: geometry

Today I came across this question:

> How far away is the horizon as seen from top of a mountain 1 mile high. (Assume the earth to be a sphere of diameter 7920 miles).
> (Correct answer 89 miles)

My Approach:

I thought of using power of a point with respect to a circle, but I am completely blank after it.

Could anyone help me solve this question.

Comment: Draw a line perpendicularly out of the circle. That's you (and the mountain). Draw tangent to the circle through your head (or the top of the mountain). Now you have a triangle with sides R, R+1 and x, where you want to find x, and one angle is 90 degrees, so you can use Pythagoras.

Comment: I know that one can use any unit system, but as we are on a scientific site, why don't you use metric system ?

Comment: @ThomasAhle that approach never crossed my mind. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie even I prefer the metric system, but I have given the question as it was when I saw it.

Comment: Fun fact about the meter: The distance from the equator to the north pole was originally defined to be 10,000km. So we know the earth's radius is $40000/(2 \pi)$ km. (Roughly, since the earth is not a perfect circle.)

Answer (score 1):

What Thomas Ahle said - the radius of the circle is 3960 miles, so the distance from the center of the earth to the top of the mountain is 3961 miles.  The distance from the top of the mountain to the horizon is a tangent line which is perpendicular to the radius.

3960^2 + x^2 = 3961^2  ---> x = 89